# Proposal: remove tag [disaster-stories]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I saw this tag searching for `disaster-recovery` tag.

[Only 5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disaster-stories?sort=newest) tagged, but only the first (at a first look) seems related to a disaster recovery.

On stackoverflow we are to ask questions, not to tell stories. Such tag is more suitable for IT disaster blogs like TDWTF.

Comment: Just edit the questions to remove the tag. With no questions attached, the tag will be purged within 24 hours.